# For loop using ejs in express node js app not outputting data but not showing any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have for loop in javascript which im using to output all the users of the database using ejs. The code is shown below. This is in a express/node js app and am using sql to store data

```
<div class = "Contacts">
  <% for(let person in persons) { %>
    <h2><%= persons[person]['fname'] %></h2>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

The data is in json and looks like this

[image]

The for loops is not printing anything but I'm also not being told any error in the command prompt

I expected the names to be printed out but they are not. Can anyone see my problem?

Comment: Try the same JS with the data (which should be in the post, not a link to a picture of formatted text) in the console. What’s “person” in the loop?

Comment: [Don't use `for..in` with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/283366). Use `for (let person of persons)` and `person.fname` instead

Comment: @DaveNewton `person` would be a key in `persons`. In this case it would an array index (assuming `persons` is the data structure in the image)

Comment: This code while not advisable should still output the `<h2>` tags with the `fname` values. At the very least you should get two `<h2>` tags. Can you post the code where you are sending the data to the view i.e the `res.render` where you are passing `persons`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this to a `for of` loop and access the object via the variable you declared, eg: person not persons

```
<div class="Contacts">
  <% for(let person of persons) { %>
    <h2><%= person.fname %></h2>
  <% } %>
</div>
```